# How can I search a hash of hashes for certain keys?

Tags: perl

I am creating a hash of hashes and trying to search or do pattern matching.

Hash is

```
$hash{$var1}{$var2}{$var3}=$value; #where $var1 =1_1 : $var2 =2_1; $var3 =3,4;
```

and i am trying to do a pattern matching with key var3
here $var4 can change values

```
for (sort keys %{$hash{'1'}{$var4}}) { # var4=2_1 : can also be 2_2 and so on 
    if ($_ =~ m/3,.*/) {  # here 
        $new = $_;        # here new should get the value 3,4
    }
}
```

The problem I am stuck with is that unless I do the following

```
for (sort keys %{$hash{'1'}{'2'}})
```

I cannot sort the keys ; In short cannot replace 2 with a variable.

Comment: I don't understand. For starters, you didn't ask any questions. You specified some desired output ("here new should get the value 3,4"), but your code does give you that output.

Comment: Could you show us the relevant part of a dump of `%hash`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a nested loop? You'll need something like this: sort the $var4 keys before going deeper down to access the values you need.

```
for my $var4 (sort keys %{$hash{'1'}}) { # var4=2_1 : can also be 2_2 and so on 
    # you can also filter the var4 keys here if you want

    for my $var3 (keys %{$hash{1}{$_}}) {
        if ($var3 =~ m/3,.*/) {  # here 
            $new = $var3;        # here new should get the value 3,4
        }
    }
}
```